# Auto right/ left indent keyword in pycharm

Tags: pycharm

In Spyder we can use `ctrl + [` for left indent and `ctrl + ]` for right indent, what's the alternative one for Pycharm?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, well, thanks
So the answer that I found is:
spyder    |  pycharm
left indent ; `ctrl + [`  | unindent; `shift + tab`
right indent ; `ctrl + ]` | indent; `tab`

Answer (score 1):

The list of shortcuts can be seen here:

[PyCharm keyboard shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/mastering-keyboard-shortcuts.html#advanced-features)

You can also configure your own here:

[Configure Keyboard Shortcuts](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-keyboard-and-mouse-shortcuts.html)